# Safari Audio.play() from blob not supported

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor, safari

I am trying to play an m4a file from the cache in safari. The error first occured on iOS (it is a Meteor Cordova app, therefore it uses Safari Webview), then I realized that it can also be reproduced in Safari on desktop. I am using the following code to try and play the audio:

```
LocalForage.getItem(track_id, (err, value)=>{
    if(err)
        throw err;
    //the loaded value is an arraybuffer of an m4a file
    let blob = new Blob([value]);
    let url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL || window || {}).createObjectURL(blob);
    let testAudio = new Audio(url);
    testAudio.play().then(()=>{console.log("play successful")}).catch((err)=>{console.error(err)});
});
```

The only error message I get is

```
DOMError: NotSupportedError (Message: "This operation is not supported")
```

If you are interested in the code used to download into the cache, it can be found [in my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750143/android-url-createobjecturl-does-not-work-properly-failed-to-load-because-no-s/40870837#40870837), the fix for chrome provided there is implemented and working, but the testing code here is as simplified as possible.

Comment: Have you been able to find out, which line causes the error you're facing?

Comment: in the second to last line, the catch() logs the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour. Localstorage is blocked by safari in private browsing mode.

Comment: Do you mean that webview on iOS always runs in private browsing mode? Also, if I test it on OSX, private browsing is not enabled and it does not work either.
Do you have an idea how could I achieve offline caching differently?

Comment: Could you add a some more information f.e. a link to the Safari documentation?